# How should we tag questions on Legend of the Galactic Heroes?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We've just gotten our first question on LotGH: [What is a more accurate translation of the title of Legend of the Galactic Heroes?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5816/what-is-a-more-accurate-translation-of-the-title-of-legend-of-the-galactic-heroe). I've provisionally tagged it with [ginga-eiyuu-densetsu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ginga-eiyuu-densetsu). In the English-speaking anime community, however, this is one of those anime that is nigh-universally known by its English-translated title, "Legend of the Galactic Heroes", and almost never by its original Japanese title, "Ginga Eiyuu Densetsu".

Problem is, `legend-of-the-galactic-heroes` is 29 characters long, which is too long to fit in a tag. Possible solutions:

- Introduce a [lotgh](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lotgh) tag and make [ginga-eiyuu-densetsu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ginga-eiyuu-densetsu) a synonym of it. (Problem: if people type "legend" or "galactic" into the tag box, they won't find this.)
- Introduce a [legend-galactic-heroes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-galactic-heroes) tag and make [ginga-eiyuu-densetsu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ginga-eiyuu-densetsu) a synonym of it. (Problem: partial titles in tags are kind of icky.)
- Do both of the above, and pick [lotgh](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lotgh) or [legend-galactic-heroes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-galactic-heroes) as the main tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that [legend-galactic-heroes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-galactic-heroes) is the way to go, no matter which synonyms we get for it.
I think people may be most likely to type `legend` first, when trying to find the tag for this series. As such, this seems like the most reasonable way to go.
Although I feel the same way about partial titles in tags, I think this case would be better of with one.

Also, I do not think [lotgh](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lotgh) should be a tag.

Comment: Since nobody seems to have any objections to this plan, I've retagged the question to [tag:legend-galactic-heroes]. If you could use your moderatorial powers to add [tag:ginga-eiyuu-densetsu] as a synonym pointing to that, that would be awesome.